# Calling PHP via Jquery without parameters

Tags: php, jquery

I'm a noob to jquery and ajax, so please bear with me :)
I want to call a php script that sends out an email when a button is clicked. I do not need to pass any data to the PHP page. Below is my jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flagbutton").click(function(){  
     // call php script here
     $("#div1").hide();
     $("#span2").text("Thanks for clicking!");
  });
});
</script>
<div style="float:right" id="div1"><span id="span1">Click the button</span>
<button id="flagbutton">The button</button></div>
<span style="float:right" id="span2"></span>
```

Below is my php code:

```
<?php
    $to = "somebody@somebody.com";
    $subject = "Subject";
    $message = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $headers = "From: test@somebody.com";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Where and how do I call the php script? 
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need jquery and ajax for this just a simple form and a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AJAX, you can do what you wanna achieve. The code below does it exactly!

```
  $("#flagbutton").click(function(){  
     $.post("php.php", function(){
       $("#div1").hide();
       $("#span2").text("Thanks for clicking!");
     });
  });
```

Or, you can do this way:

```
  $("#flagbutton").click(function(){  
     $.post("php.php").done(function(){
       $("#div1").hide();
       $("#span2").text("Thanks for clicking!");
     });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay. This was my first post on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("path_to_php",{}).done(function(data)
    {
       //ajax completed, the variable data will return which the PHP will echo out. 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flagbutton").click(function(){  
     $.ajax({ 
        url: your_url,


        beforeSend: function() {
            // you can show some loading things
        },      
        complete: function() {
                        //remove the loading things here
        },          
        success: function(response) {
           $("#div1").hide();
                  $("#span2").text("Thanks for clicking!"); 

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

  });
});
</script>
```